# JSON dumping an object with two inner objects

Tags: python, json

I have a dictionary `track_data = {}`. I then put an array of songs into it under the key `recent_tracks` as follows:

`track_data['recent_tracks'] = [x.track.artist.name + " - " + x.track.title for x in recent_tracks]`

I then dump it (along with similar key value pairs) and pass it to the front end of my application as follows:

`return HttpResponse(json.dumps(track_data), content_type="application/json")`

The guy doing the front end then accesses it using `recent_tracks[0]` to get the first index which would give him say `Haim - The Wire`. However, he wants the artist name and track name to be passed back as separate objects  under `recent_tracks`. So say he wished to access the artist name he would write `recent_tracks[0].artist`.

Can I give the key `recent_tracks` child objects that can then be dumped as JSON and passed back in that format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attributes in JSON are keys in a Python dictionary. So you just have to create the proper dictionary when creating your `recent_tracks`list:

```py
track_data['recent_tracks'] = [
    {"artist": x.track.artist.name, "title": x.track.title}
    for x in recent_tracks
]
```

for example.

Comment: Precisely what I was after! Textbook answer.